# Rails 3 functional tests: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: controller, action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, activerecord, functional-testing

When running functional tests on my controller code in a Rails 3 project, I have a fatal error; the `params` variable contains `controller` and `action`, and ActiveModel is not happy about it:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: controller, action
    /Users/phooze/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activemodel-3.2.1/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:48:in `process_removed_attributes'
    /Users/phooze/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activemodel-3.2.1/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:20:in `debug_protected_attribute_removal'
    /Users/phooze/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activemodel-3.2.1/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:12:in `sanitize'
    /Users/phooze/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activemodel-3.2.1/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:228:in `sanitize_for_mass_assignment'
    /Users/phooze/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:75:in `assign_attributes'
    /Users/phooze/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:495:in `initialize'
    /Users/phooze/Documents/rails-app/app/controllers/credentials_controller.rb:40:in `new'
```

The application call is to the "new" method (where the error is occurring), the code is:

```
  # Credential#create (POST)
  def create
      @credential = Credential.new(params)
      # ... controller continues
  end
```

Finally, my test case:

```
  test "should create credential" do
    assert_difference('Credential.count', 1) do
      post :create, { :fid => "foobarbaz", :credentials_hash => "f00ba7f00ba7", :uid => "10023", :cid => "342" }
    end
    assert_response :created
  end
```

Changing my controller code to a "separate" parameter hash containing ONLY the fid, credentials_hash, uid, and cid makes it work.  I'm pretty sure Rails is trying to be "nice" and provide me with addtional values for testing, but it seems to be causing problems.

Any recommendations on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have set `config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict`
in your test environment only, but not in development or production, because `params` always contains `controller` and `action`, in any environment.

I think the best-practice recommendation here is to always use `form_for`, so that you'd have your credentials in `params[:credential]`, or, indeed, do `params.slice(:fid, :uid, etc)`.

Comment: Thanks.  The reason I'm not using params[:credential] is that it's a Web API call (there is no "new" method in my controller) -- and some of the parameters are query string, so "credential[uid]" isn't unreasonable on the query string... but not the first thing I thought to do :)